# Dimension of vector Space of 2 by 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following question is regarding the dimension of a certain vector space.

$$
A \in M_{22} : A\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I do not exactly know what the question is asking here. Please help me...

Comment: Perhaps dimensions of vector space containing matrices A such that A times that matrix is 0 matrix.

Comment: It is worth remembering that $M_{2\times 2}$ is a four dimensional vector space with canonical basis $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is in the subspace, then the following equations hold:

$$ a + 2b = 0, \ c + 2d = 0 $$

The other two equations you get from setting the entries of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ equal to zero are redundant.

Therefore $a = -2b$ and $c = -2d$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: From that i can see that we lose 2 degrees of freedom. This implies that the dimension will be 4 - 2 = 2.

Comment: That's correct.